# I am trying to get folder path in text file

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to get all folders path and store them into a text file.

```
ls
cd ls

path=pwd
```

this way storing path into the path variable. 
Then I have to get all this paths into a text file.
Can someone tell me a better way to do this. Current method isn't working.

Also can i do it better with some other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this command:

```
ll -lt|grep "^d"|awk '{print $NF}' >/tmp/t.txt
```

# list the all file and directory in some current dir

```
ll -lt
```

# filter the directory

```
grep "^d"
```

# print the directory name

```
awk '{print $NF}'
```

# write the result into a text file

```
> /tmp/t.txt
```

if you want get the full dir path, you can try this command:

```
ll -lt|grep "^d"|awk -v P="$(pwd)" '{print P"/"$NF}'>/tmp/t.txt
```

Comment: Thats good. But it is giving me the folder name.. How can I get path to those folders